# SSH Through Firewall Using Putty

Tags: ssh, vpn, firewall, putty, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to ssh to my raspberry pi (note: i know the connection works, I have tested it on non firewall'd networks).

I'm behind a school firewall, but port 22 is open.

My pi uses port 2000 (for obscuring purposes).

How would i go about doing this? Would creating a vpn(openvpn?) be an easier solution?

Would Configuring putty to tunnel be the best decision and how would i go about doing this?

Also i am new, if im doing anything wrong please let me know

Comment: Are you trying to tunnel traffic using ssh?

Comment: No i simply want to get access to the terminal

Comment: OK, my guess (which from experience) is that your school has a deep packet inspection (DPI), so changing the ssh port will not work. Try tunneling the traffic through a proxy.

Comment: Ssh is allowed on the network. However only under port 22. The port i have my pi on which is 2000 is blocked.

Comment: If ssh on the port 22 is allowed then why don't you just change it to 22?

Comment: I changed the port for security reasons

Comment: So there are two options: A) change it back to 22. or B) proxy ssh through port 443(HTTPS port). I can't think of something else.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your question, you are trying to ssh to your Raspberry Pi from your school through port 2000 which is closed on the school firewall and only port ssh (TCP 22) is allowed. You have two options:

1. Change your Raspberry Pi listening port to 22.
2. Set up a laptop/desktop/VM in your home network (that can access your Raspberry Pi on port 2000) with regular ssh service (port TCP 22) then:

   - Use it as a "proxy" by doing SSH to this machine and then SSH to your Raspberry Pi
   - SSH directly through the newly created machine using the following command:

> ssh -L 9999:Raspberry_Pi_LOCAL_IP:2000 VM_PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS
>
> *For example if VM_PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS is 151.101.129.69 (took IP address of superuser.com as an example) and your Raspberry_Pi_LOCAL_IP is 192.168.1.10 the command would look like:*
>
> ssh -L 9999:192.168.1.10:2000 151.101.129.69

- Then all you need is to ssh to your localhost on port 9999

  > ssh user@localhost -p 9999

Or by using Putty directly, but make sure you change the port to 9999 and hostname/IP to localhost or 127.0.0.1

Comment: You understood my question, however i was looking for a method that wouldnt require any other hardware. In this case if these are the only two options wouldnt it be better to just create a vpn on my pi?

Answer (score 0):

You could do a port forwarding on your internet router (at home) from port 22 (on your public IP address) to port 2000 (on your Raspberry Pi IP address).

This way when you ssh from your school (using port 22) you will be using your router's public IP address assigned by your service provider. The router will forward packets received on port 22 to your Raspberry Pi IP address on port 2000.